# If $ f(f(f(x)))=x$, does$ f(x)=x$ necessarily follow?

Tags: functions, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Does $f(f(f(x)))=x \implies  f(x)=x$? Is it necessary for it to follow? How do we prove this? Do we have to substitute some special $x$? Or is it some other consideration of its properties?

Edit: does it follow in the special case when f is surjective? Or would we wind up with the same thing?

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.ies-math.com/math/java/calc/invfunc/invfunc.html

Comment: That's a nice example, but I worried OP might not like it because of the issue at $x = -1$.  Of course if you work in projective space then everything works out fine: you send $-1 \mapsto \infty \mapsto 1 \mapsto -1$.

Comment: If we assume that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has the intermediate value property, then the answer is yes; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/3rd-iterate-of-a-continuous-function-equals-identity-function

Comment: @Daniel Mclaury: We can put $f(x)=x$ is $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f(x)=\frac{x-3}{x+1}$ if $x\not \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Kelenner: Nice!

Comment: More solutions: [Can the Identity Map be a repeated composition one other function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195852/can-the-identity-map-be-a-repeated-composition-one-other-function)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.  For instance, consider $f(x) = e^{2 \pi i/3} x$.

Finding a function which equals another function when iterated is called finding a "fractional iterate," "iterative root," or "functional root."  In your case, you're talking about functional cube roots of the identity function.  The problem of finding functional roots of the identity function is apparently known as "Babbage's equation," as the problem was studied by Charles Babbage at the beginning of the 19th century.  You can find lots more information by Googling "Babbage's Equation."

Answer (score 2):

Another set of solutions:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-i \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\left(x-c_1\right){}^2+c_2}+3 c_1-x\right)$$

Comment: Showing how you got this would make it easier to verify.

Answer (score 2):

A variant on Daniel's answer:

Define $$S : \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$ by $$S(n) = n+1.$$

Then $$S(S(S(n))) = n+1+1+1 = n+3 = n,$$ but $$S(0) = 1 \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Anixx's solution,
suppose
$f(x) = ax+b$.

Then
$f(f(x))
=a(ax+b)+b
=a^2x+b(a+1)
$
and
$f(f(f(x)))
=a(a^2x+b(a+1))+b
=a^3x+b(a(a+1)+1)
$.

If
$f(f(f(x))) = x$,
then
$a^3 = 1$
and
either
$b = 0$
or
$a(a+1)+1 = 0$.

For $b=0$,
then
$f(x) = wx$
works if
$w^3 = 1$.

For
$a(a+1)+1 = 0$,
then,
since
$a^3-1 = (a-1)(a^2+a+1)
$,
then
$a^3 = 1$
and
$a \ne 1$.
This is the same as before.

Therefore,
all linear solutions
are of the form
$wx+b$
for any $b$,
where
$w^3 = 1$.