# $ f(f(f(x))) = x $ with $ f(x) \ne x $ and $ f(f(x)) \ne x$

Tags: functions, fixed-points, iterated-function-system

I recently came to wonder if there are function that, when applied, iteratively, become a fix point, but only after a certain amount of iteration.

Formally, let's define the following:
$f_1(x) = g(x)$, $f_n(x) = g(f_{n-1}(x))$

Now I'm generally looking for any $f_k$ with $f_k(x) = x$, and $f_j(x) \neq x, \forall j\ |\ 0<j< k$.
In general, this is easy if you have a "combined" function (sorry I don't know the proper name here) with multiple "ifs".

However, I would like to constraint $g(x)$ to be a function without any "ifs" and without modulo arithmetic.

So far, I've managed to solve this for $f_2$ and $f_4$:

- $f_2$: $g(x) = -x$
- $f_4$: $g(x) = x\cdot i$

*NB: At the time of writing this I noticed that $f_2$ and $f_4$ break if x = 0*

Now I would like to find a solution for $f_3$, or, in fact, for an $f_k$, or a proof that this isn't possible.

Unfortunately I don't really know where to start my research at or if this is even possible. So I thought I'd ask the MathExchange community and see if we get somewhere :)

Comment: What kind of functions are you looking for specifically, i.e. what are their domain and codomain/range limited to? For instance, if you broaden your scope beyond $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ to matrices (which one can interpret as functions in their own right - linear transformations), the problem becomes next to trivial depending on your knowledge of linear algebra.

Comment: Do rotations by 120 degrees in the plane satisfy?

Comment: I'm actually open to any kind of solution here and looking to learn something new. How would it look like for matrices?
How would you encode a 120 degree rotation in the plane as a function?

Comment: You wrote "I would like to constraint g(x) to be a function without any "ifs" and without modulo arithmetic." and "I'm actually open to any kind of solution here". Which one is it?

Comment: A 120 degree rotation is $z \mapsto z\cdot e^{2\pi i / 3}$

Comment: I'm open to any kind of solution following the constrained I mentioned - sorry for not being more specific on this. It's just super trivial to me using ifs or modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Regarding the 120 degree rotation: That's neat! Do I understand correctly, that the `3` makes it 120 degree?

Comment: Do you mean for any $x$, $g_n^i(x)$ has minimal period as $n$ or the whole $g_n$. $f_2$ and $f_4$ do they count as valid example?

Comment: I think I mean the former one, but I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.
$f_2$ and $f_4$ are some example for $k=2$ or $k=4$., so the function for $k=3$ ($f_3$) can be completely unrelated to $f_2$ and $f_4$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the Identity Map be a repeated composition one other function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195852/can-the-identity-map-be-a-repeated-composition-one-other-function)

Comment: @MJD it answers it only partly, as the author is searching for $k$ to be prime, and does not constrain that it's only an identity after $k$ iterations.
see below, Pavel R. has answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another function:

$$
f(x)=\frac{x+3}{-x-2}
$$

You get

$$
f(f(x))=\frac{-2x-3}{x+1}\,,\qquad f(f(f(x)))=x.
$$

*Remark:* There are infinitely many functions of that kind. For example

$$
f(x)=\frac{x-1}{3x-2},\qquad f(x)=\frac{7x-3}{19x-8},\qquad \text{etc.}
$$

We can find them very easily. Let

$$
f(x)=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D},\qquad A,B,C,D\in\mathbb R,\ AD-BC\neq 0.
$$

We compose it with itself twice and we get

$$
f(f(f(x)))=\frac{\left(A^3+2ABC+BCD\right)x+A^2B+ABD+B^2C+BD^2}{\left(A^2C+BC^2+ACD+CD^2\right)x+ABC+2BCD+D^3}=\frac{1x+0}{0x+1}\,.
$$

Now we solve the system of four equations:

\begin{align*}
A^3+2ABC+BCD&=1\\
A^2B+ABD+B^2C+BD^2&=0\\
A^2C+BC^2+ACD+CD^2&=0\\
ABC+2BCD+D^3&=1.
\end{align*}

Suppose $A,B,C,D$ are nonzero real numbers. Then the system has infinitely many solutions in the form:

$$
D=-A-1,\quad C=\frac{-A^2-A-1}B
$$
and $A,B$ are set arbitrarily.

*Remark 2:*

The previous procedure is not effective for solving the equation $f_k(x)=x$ with $k\geq 4$ due to larger systems of nonlinear equations. It is better to look at the problem through a special difference equation

$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{Ax_n+B}{Cx_n+D}\,,\qquad C\neq 0,\quad AD-BC\neq 0,
$$

see *Brand, Louis, "A sequence defined by a difference equation," American Mathematical Monthly 62, September 1955, 489–492.* I will only mention the part of the article that is related to our problem. We will deal with the simpler form of the equation

$$
x_{n+1}=A-\frac{B}{x_n}\,.
$$

Setting $x_n=y_{n+1}/y_n$ we get

$$
y_{n+2}-Ay_{n+1}+By_n=0
$$

which is a linear difference equation of the second order with constant coefficients. It can be solved using a characteristic equation

$$
r^2-Ar+B=0.
$$

Let $A^2-4B<0$. Then the characteristic equation has two complex roots:

$$
r_{1,2}=\sqrt B\left(\cos\theta\pm\mathrm i\,\sin\theta\right)
$$
where $\theta$ satisfies $\cos\theta=A/(2\sqrt B)$ and $0<\theta<\pi$.

Let us assume that

$$
\frac{\theta}{\pi}=\frac pq\,,\qquad \text{$p$ and $q$ are coprime.}
$$

Under these conditions, the sequence $x_n$ contains only $q$ distinct terms  $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_q$ which repeat indefinitely in this order, i.e. $x_{q+j}=x_j$, $j=1,\dots,q$, see the AMM article. If we define

$$
f(x)=A-\frac Bx
$$

we can express the previous conclusion as $f_q(x)=x$.

Reversely, $f_k(x)=x$, if

$$
r_{1,2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{k}\pm\mathrm i\,\sin\frac{\pi}{k}\,.
$$

The characteristic equation is in the form

$$
r^2-\left(2\cos\frac{\pi}k\right)\cdot r+1=0.
$$

Thus $A=2\cos\frac{\pi}k$, $B=1$. We can conclude

$$
\color{red}{\boldsymbol{f(x)=2\cos\frac{\pi}k-\frac 1x\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad f_k(x)=x,\quad k\geq 2.}}
$$

Comment: Cool solution! How did you find it?

Comment: Look at the remark I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is really thorough. :) 
I was wondering how you came up with the form $\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$ in the first place, and how would you compose the same for other $k$ values, eg $k=5$, so that $f(f(f(f(f(x))))) = x$?

Comment: It is connected with rational difference equations very closely. Tomorrow I am going to write some details of setting $A,B,C,D$ for a general positive integer $k$. For $k=5$ set $A=\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{2}$, $B=-1$, $C=1$ and $D=0$ and you get $f(f(f(f(f(x)))))=x$.

Comment: Thank you for your second remark. That's perfect and thorough! This completely answer my question :)

Answer (score 1):

For $f_3$ you could consider
$$f(x)=1-\frac1x=\frac{x-1}{x}$$ for a suitable domain.
Because then $$ff(x)=\frac{\frac{x-1}{x}-1}{\frac{x-1}{x}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
And then $$fff(x)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x-1}{x}}=x$$

Comment: love it! very simple. :) 
Now I'm wondering if one could generalize that equation to work for an $f_k$.
Also, how does one find such an equation?